# HTML/Javascript button doesn't return alert

Tags: javascript, html

I made a HTML page with a button, that displays a message saying: "This is a message". Everything looks fine, but when I press the button don't get a message. I checked for any mistakes, but I couldn't find anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing JavaScript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="Button.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Javascript</h1>
        <p>I am testing JS on this page.<br/>
        This is a button.</p>

    <script>
        var message = "This is a message";
        function popUp()
        {
            alert(message);
        }
    </script>
    <button type="button" onclick="press()">Press me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you know there is a Javascript Console in your browser? Press F12. You'd see an error `undefined function press()` if you click the button.

Comment: @Kenney Thanks, that'll be very usefull in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `onclick="press()"`:

```
onclick="popUp()"
```

Comment: Nah, sometimes this happens with all of us. :)

Answer (score 3):

You should call to `onclick="popUp()"`

Answer (score 1):

You dont have a function named as "press()" declared, change the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing JavaScript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="Button.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Javascript</h1>
        <p>I am testing JS on this page.<br/>
        This is a button.</p>

    <script>
        var message = "This is a message";
        function popUp()
        {
            alert(message);
        }
    </script>
    <button type="button" onclick="popUp()">Press me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```